# Yajra datatable global search for comma separated values not working

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

`Actual Result`

Using Yajra datatable when I search for data (*column having comma separated values*) using **global search** it doesn't work and shows as empty result for permission column

`Expected Result`

https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/advanced/renderSearchArrays.html

searching works fine for comma seperated value in Jquery datatable however same behaviour is not working with Yajra datatable

`What have you done:-` Implemented same behaviour in Yajra Datatable present in the link of Expected Result

`code working in Jquery datatable`

```
render: {
          _: '[, ].name',
          sp: '[].name'
        },
```

`code not working in Yajra datatable`

```
->render([
           '_' => '[, ].name',
           'sp' => '[].name',
         ])
```

result in `Undefined array key 0`

done some research and found similar [github issue](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1512) not working

my project composer.json `"yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^10.0"`

permission is fetched using this code (not sure do we really need use addColumn for permissions?)

```
->addColumn('permissions', function ($user) {
                return implode(',', $user->permissions->pluck('name')->toArray());
          })
```

Can anyone suggest how to achieve working global search for multi value single column?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after struggling for few days I was able to figure it out using Yajra Datatables

```
->addColumn('role', function (User $user) {
                return implode(', ', $user->getRoleNames()->toArray());
            })
```

```
->filterColumn('role', function ($query, $keyword) {
                $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
                    $q->whereRaw("roles.name like ?", ["%$keyword%"]);
                });
            })
```